# How to open a workbooks with the path file?

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with Workbooks(). In the below code I want the user to pick the file and get the path file from the dialogbox. All these steps are working. However I am struggling the use `pathKeys`. It seems when I write `Workbooks(pathkeys)` I have an error 9 (Script our of range).

```
Sub getData()

    Dim diagBoxkeys As FileDialog
    Dim pathKeys As String
    
    Set diagBoxkeys = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diagBoxkeys.Title = "Keys File " & FileType
    diagBoxkeys.Filters.Clear
    diagBoxkeys.Show
    If diagBoxkeys.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        pathKeys = diagBoxkeys.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  
    MsgBox (pathKeys)
    Dim wbKeys As Workbook
    ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Set wbKeys = GetObject(pathKeys)
    Workbooks(pathKeys).Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(1)  
    wbKeys.Close Savechanges:=False
 
End Sub
```

However when in this code I replace `Workbooks(pathKeys)` with `Workbooks("Keys_2021-12-27_13_43_21_utf-8.csv")` it works perfectly.

I don't understand why pathKeys is not accepted as `pathKeys = C:\Users\tn5809\Documents\PROJETS\PORTAL_APRR\Keys_2021-12-27_13_43_21_utf-8.csv`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `Set wbKeys = Workbooks.Open(pathKeys)` and then reference `wbKeys` rather than `Workbooks(pathKeys)`

Comment: Also, `& FileType` isn't defined and `ScreenUpdating = False` should be `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (I wouldn't put that line in at all though).

Comment: Okayy, can you explain why you suggest me to do that ? As this part is working or there is something in your answer i don't understant

Comment: Which part?  I'm guessing you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, as `FileType` isn't defined it's set as a Variant with no value.  So `"Keys File " & FileType` is the same as writing `"Keys File "`.  With `Option Explicit` in place `ScreenUpdating = False` returns a `Variable not defined` error.  You'll also need to remember to turn it back on ([Application.ScreenUpdatingProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating))

Comment: Okay I undestand what you mean. Btw I am not an expert ov vba, actually this is my first time, so i'm picking code from here and there. I get back to you in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work better for you.

```
'This should appear at the top of all modules.
'It forces you to declare all variables.
'Tools ~ Options ~ Require Variable Declaration.
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    
    '*** If Macro_Portal is not file containing this code: ***
    Dim MacroPortalPath As String
    MacroPortalPath = OpenFile ' or MacroPortalPath = "C:\...\...\Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm"
    Dim MacroPortal As Workbook
    MacroPortal = Workbooks.Open(MacroPortalPath)
    '*** If Macro Portal is the file containing this code: ***
    'Dim MacroPortal As Workbook
    'Set MacroPortal = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim pathKeys As String
    pathKeys = OpenFile
    
    If pathKeys <> "" Then
        Dim wrkBk As Workbook
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(pathKeys)
        
        'Best to use sheet name rather than where it is in workbook (can be moved by user).
        'You could replace MacroPortal with ThisWorkbook and remove first block of code in this procedure.
        wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").columns2.Copy Destination:=MacroPortal.Worksheets("Sheet1").Column(1)
        wrkBk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Public Function OpenFile() As String

    Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
    Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With dialogBox
        .Title = "Keys File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            OpenFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you. Yes I am using this vba code from a separate excel file. As i want to import data from the excel file picked by the user. So i have few questions about your code. When a sub() is a public function i can get variables value from another sub() ? I don't understand how the code is executed, when I run `getData()`, at the lines where `pathKeys = openFile` is defined, it runs `openFile()` ? Also, why use `Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(pathKeys)` and not `Set wbKeys = GetObject(pathKeys)`, I read it is less process.

Comment: Anyway thank you for that help !

Comment: `Public` when assigned to a procedure or function means the procedure or function can be called from another module.  If you changed `OpenFile` to `Private`  then `GetData` could still use it as it's in the same module, but a procedure outside the module could not.

Comment: `OpenFile` is a function meaning it can return a value to the procedure that called it.  So `MacroPortalPath = OpenFile` asks you to select a file and stores the result in `MacroPortalPath`, while `pathKeys = OpenFile` calls the same function and stores the result in `pathKeys`.  Note that at the end of the function is the line `OpenFile = .SelectedItems(1)`  - this is where the result of the function is assigned to the function name (which can be treated as a variable in itself I guess).

Comment: You can pass variables to procedures and functions within the function name.  So, you could write the function name as `Public Function OpenFile(StartDirectory As String) As String` and use it within the function - `.InitialFileName = StartDirectory`.  You'd pass the StartDirectory value when you call the function - `pathKeys = OpenFile("C:\")`

Comment: So you're telling me the code should be in a Module and not in ThisWorkbook or on Sheet1 ?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the best place to put it.  It'll probably work in ThisWorkbook or Sheet1, but generally those are used to capture sheet and book events such as changing the value in a cell or opening a new file.